# Minimize f(x, y) = $|x + y -3|^2 + |2x + y + 1|^2 + |3x + y - 2|^2$ using least squares

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, least-squares, adjoint-operators

Problem: minimize f(x, y) = $|x + y -3|^2 + |2x + y + 1|^2 + |3x + y - 2|^2$ using least squares, x and y complex

I am getting lost on how to approach this problem. In my book, the least squares approximation problem is set up as finding the line of best fit through a fixed set of points $(x_i, y_i$)

The only idea I have is the absolute value squared looks like the inner product <-> length equation... but the terms inside don't factor to anything..

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Update: It seems $f(x, y)$ is the length of the vector $(x + y - 3, 2x + y + 1, 3x + y - 2)$ squared? For least squares approximation, I think I need to write something of the form $Ax = b$... been stuck what to do next though

Comment: @hardmath sorry I did omit a plus sign in the title. I re-iterated the question in the body, but I'm not sure what else is there to expand on?

Comment: Thanks!  Now let's think about minimizing $f(x,y)$ using the length interpretation.  What vector has length $f(x,y)$?  How does varying $x,y$ of this vector affect the length?  It might help to think "geometrically" in three dimensions.

Comment: Oh... it seems $f(x, y)$ is the length of the vector $(x + y - 3, 2x + y + 1, 3x + y - 2)$ squared? Not entirely sure where to go from here but I can start working on it. Thanks!

Comment: @hardmath I've been stuck after this, couldn't find/figure out anything that lets me proceed. Another hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 1 \\
3 &1 \end{bmatrix}, \vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$b=\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

You are trying to minimize
$$\| A \vec{x} -b \|^2$$ meaning youneed to find the best approximation (or least square solution) to 
$$A \vec{x} =b$$

Comment: Ah thanks, feel kinda dumb now was mucking around with something like that but unnecessarily complicating it in my head. Only question - does this apply regardless of the field? (complex numbers in this case). In my book there's no mention of anything, but it seems you wouldn't get complex solutions unless you started with complex numbers? (guess that makes sense - any imaginary part would be extra length that doesn't make it "closer" to anything?)

Comment: For the methodology it makes no difference. Note that since $A$ and $b$ are real, the least square solution has to be real: if the least square would be complex, then the real part would be closer to $b$...

Comment: I see, thank you very much! Sorry one more thing I forgot... do we/how do we know the solution is unique? Googling I got various answers such as $A^{*}A$ being invertible, or something to do with the dimensions of A and b, or the rank of A, none with a real explanation

Comment: @Raekye First it should be noted that there always exists a solution to the problem, let's call one such (potentially unique) solution $v$. 

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ then if $\text{rank}(A) = m < n,$ there are infinitely many solutions which satisfy $Ax=b$ exactly. By the rank-nullity theorem, we know that $\dim(\ker(A)) >0$. Now, take our solution $v$ and any vector $w \in \ker(A)$ and we have that $v+w$ is also a solution -- hence there are infinitely many such solutions (the kernel translated by $v$). This type of system is often called an underdetermined' system....(1/2)

Comment: @ Raekye Now, if the $\text{rank}(A) = n \leq m,$ we call this an overdetermined system, and the solution is unique. (2/2)

Comment: @Raekye The theory tells you the the least square solutions are exactly the solutions to $A^*A \vec{x}=A^*b$. So the solution is unique exactly when  this system has unique solution. Since you know how to solve the system, you can easily find if the sol is unique.